# Virtual function hiding in derived class

Tags: c++, overloading, overriding

I have two classes related by inheritance:-

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f(int x)
    {
        cout << "BASE::int" << endl;
    }
    virtual void f(double x)
    {
        cout << "BASE::double" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void f(str::string s)
    {
        cout << "DERIVED::string" << endl;
    }
};
```

I have provided same method in derived class with different parameters. That means rather than overriding I am hiding base class versions of this function. So, below calls are expected and clear to me.

```
std::string str("Hello");
Base b;
b.f(1);        //calls base class version.
b.f(str);      //error.

Derived d;
d.f(1);        //error.
d.f(str);      //calls derived class version.
```

But I am not able get clarification for this last scenario.

```
Base *b = new Derived;
b->f(str);     //results in error.
```

Would compiler not bind this call to derived version of f using vtables and vptrs. But instead it's doing something else. Can anyone provide me complete path how compiler would try to resolve this call as per language mechanisms.

Comment: How the compiler resolves the situation, is that the name lookup will choose a class first. If Base is chosen, then only functions available in base class will be used. If Derived is chosen, and f can be found from Derived class, then functions of Base are never found. So it really depends on the type of the pointer, which set of functions you can use.

Answer (score 2):

If your pointer is of type `Base*` then you can only "see" members that are defined in class `Base`.  The compiler doesn't (or pretends not to) "know" that the variable really points to an instance of `Derived`, even if you just assigned one to it on the previous line.

When you declare a variable to be of type `Base*`, you're telling the compiler:  treat this as something that could point to a `Base` or to *any class* derived from it.  So you can't access members that are defined in a particular derived class, because there's no guarantee that the pointer actually points to an instance of that derived class.

Answer (score 1):

The vtable only enters the picture at runtime. The generated assembly would have a lookup of the vptr value for a function and a jump to that address. This also means that the polymorphism is "restricted" to functions that `Base` knows about. Note that this is what makes more sense as well - the definition of a class should only depend on itself and its parents. If you wanted to make `Base* b` aware of the virtual functions implemented by `Derived`, you would end up with the number of vtable entries in `Base`s depending on its children.